# how to perform synchronization(or replication) between two master database with different version?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, replication

I hava a database application in mysql 5.5 innodb. I want to install the same setup in mysql 5.6 version. I will keep the both.

Every changes in first database will happen in the second one or changes in second will make changes in first database.

Please let me know the simplest way to achieve this. OS is linux.

Comment: I don't think they can both be masters. One has to be a master, the other a slave.

Comment: why it cant be happen. Is it not possible to insert in any one of the two database? Please elaborate so i can understand.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626756/mysql-replication-be-bi-directional

Comment: Sorry i am new, if you explain a bit more than this link(tough for me to understand no process described), i would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [replicate between 5.5 and 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-compatibility.html):

> MySQL supports replication from one major version to the next higher
>   major version. For example, you can replicate from a master running
>   MySQL 4.1 to a slave running MySQL 5.0, from a master running MySQL
>   5.0 to a slave running MySQL 5.1, and so on.

You certainly can have multi-master replication.

There are a couple caveats:

> The use of more than 2 MySQL Server versions is not supported in
>   replication setups involving multiple masters, regardless of the
>   number of master or slave MySQL servers.

I think you're good on the next one between 5.5 and 5.6:

> You cannot replicate from a newer master to an older slave using
>   statement-based replication if the statements to be replicated use SQL
>   features available on the master but not on the slave.

Comment: will you please show me the procedure or can give me some link where i can find steps and follow to make such arrangement.

Comment: @AamirSohail, sorry, I thought you were asking if you **can** do it (between versions), since there are plenty of guides to show you how to setup replication. Google `MySQL master master replication` or `MySQL multimaster replication`. Don't skip the part about configuring auto_increment.

Comment: this was helpful. I have one more question. Will it create problem if I configure one master as mysql 5.5 version and other one with 5.6?

Comment: @AamirSohail, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i have performed the master master replication. Thank you for the advice and answers. I also marking your answer as correct so this one get close.